# Python: Read in Colors Codes from JSON

Tags: python, terminal, colors, ansi-escape

I am interested in creating a project where a python script will create colored output. The structure of my project is such that I would like to create a `settings.json` file (handled by users) that contains color codes (ANSI).

Here is what my `settings.json` file looks like. Note that in a bash profile, you'd normally use one escape character to indicate color codes but Python will not allow me to read a file with only one escape character. :

```
{
  "column_head_color": {
    "group1": "\\033[91m",
    "group2": null
  }
}
```

And here is the main module:

```
import json


# import settings
with open('settings.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    settings = json.load(file)


for column in settings['column_head_color']:
    color_setting = settings['column_head_color'][column]

    if color_setting is None:
    # if setting is null, reset color
        settings['column_head_color'][column] = "\033[0m"   # reset; if I change the string to "\\033[94m", output shows actual color

    else:
        # if there is a color code present, should I replace "\\" with "\"?
        settings['column_head_color'][column] = settings['column_head_color'][column].replace("\\\\", "\\")



print("{}This is the group1".format(settings['column_head_color']['group1']))       # output shows the color code, but it does not actually format the text
print("{}This is the group2".format(settings['column_head_color']['group2']))       # output here works, because it was hard coded manually
```

I have tried replacing two escape characters with one, and I have tried using the `repr()` function, but to no avail. I have only gone as far as showing an output that looks like something like this:

```
>>> python main.py
\033[91mOutput
```

For `group2`, the color code works because I manually entered the code in the script. But when I read it in a similar string for `group1` from the JSON file, Python does not interpret it the same way. How do I prompt my python program to interpret that string as a color code?

Comment: `\` is used to escape unprintable characters when you define a string. However, in your case here maybe a better design would be to store only the color value in your JSON (eg 0 or 91) rather than the entire escape sequence. Just insert that value when you print.

Comment: @Tim thank you for the comment! This is an excellent recommendation, probably easier to implement. Out of curiosity, what would be the appropriate method to have the string interpreted correctly (supposing that the entire code must be entered into the JSON file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow these steps to make it work:

1. Format your json file like this:

   ```json
   {
       "Black" : "30",
       "Red" : "31",
       "Green" : "32",
       "Yellow" : "33",
       "Blue" : "34",
       "Magenta" : "35",
       "Cyan" : "36",
       "White" : "37"
   }
   ```
2. Find and load the JSON file

   ```js
   // Replace PATH_TO__FILE and FILE_NAME accordingly  
   const colors = require('PATH_TO_FILE/FILE_NAME.json')
   ```
3. Create a function to output in different colors. For instance:

   ```js
   function consoleLogColor(color, text) {
       console.log(`\x1b[${colors[color]}m%s\x1b[0m`, text);
   }
   consoleLogColor('Blue', 'HI');
   ```